# How do I test HTML that has to be rendered with testacular and jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I want to test if a directive binds the correct jquery functions to the DOM and that they work.

For instance i want to test if an element is visible after it was slid up with $.slideUp() or i want to execute a click event on an html input.

It seems that i need to somehow attach the compiled directive to the DOM to make this happen. I've watched the [testing directives video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB5b67Cg6bc) where he says that it is possible but he doesnt mention how you do it.

I'm kinda stuck.

Heres the link to the failing test: http://plnkr.co/edit/PojXf8?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of things:

First, if you want to use jQuery with Angular, it needs to be loaded before Angular is, so move its script tag before Angular's.

Second, you're right about attaching the directive to the DOM. In a `beforeEach` call, you can use jQuery to create a host div and then remove that div in an `afterEach` call.

[Here that is in a fork of your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PT0AdW?p=preview).

That said, you only need your div in the DOM to check for visibility, which I'm not even sure you need to do in most cases. For example, you could use Sinon to spy on the `slideUp` call to make sure it happens and rely on jQuery's tests that it actually works.

And you can always trigger clicks directly just by calling `elm.click()` using jQuery.